# My code is failing a mysterious edge case

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on Hackerrank's Migratory Birds [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/migratory-birds/problem).

> Given an array of bird sightings where every element represents a bird type id, determine the id of the most frequently sighted type. If more than 1 type has been spotted that maximum amount, return the smallest of their ids.

My solution is as follows:

```
def migratoryBirds(arr):
    _dict = {}
    for key in arr:
        if key not in _dict:
            _dict[key] = 1
        else:
            _dict[key] += 1
    _max_key = 0
    _max_cnt = 0
    for key in _dict:
        if _dict[key] > _max_cnt:
            _max_key = key
            _max_cnt = _dict[key]
    return _max_key
```

It is failing a single test case (case 4).  Since it is really large, I can't paste it here.  Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The page you sent us to requires a login. Are you just trying to find out which key has the maximum count?  What are you supposed to return if two keys are tied?

Comment: @FrankYellin, you can just close the login pop-up to see the problem.  In case of a tie, pick the smaller key.  For example with `arr = [1,1,2,2,3]`, the answer should be `1`.

Comment: Unclear what the problem is, but I think majority of the function could  be replaced by `Counter(arr)`

Comment: @OneCricketeer, which `import` do I need to use `Counter`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Comment: Please note that questions on SO should always be self contained, so you should include a  short description of the actual problem*in the question itself", not as a link.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's my solution, It should work**

```
def migratory_birds(arr):
    x = dict()
    for i in arr:
        if i not in x.keys():
            x[i] = arr.count(i)

    li = [k for k, v in x.items() if v == max(x.values())]

    return min(li)
```

Alternatively, You can use the `Counter` function from the `collections` as suggested by [OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer)

```
from collections import Counter

def migratory_birds(arr):
    x = Counter(arr)
    li = [k for k, v in x.items() if v == max(x.values())]

    return min(li)
```

Comment: Same comment as above, just use a Counter dictionary. Calling `.count()` over every element is quadratic runtime

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yeah, no need for counting for each id using counter variables

Comment: No. Use `from collection import Counter` then simply `x = Counter(arr)`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Aah, ok I get it now

Comment: @OneCricketeer I added that solution too to my answer

Comment: @SidharthMudgil, your code works but need this correction: `def migratory_birds(arr)`.

Comment: @CaTx Oh! you can change the parameter name to anything, You can change it in Hackerrank too

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for helping out, everyone!  I found the error.  The code should have been:

```
def migratoryBirds(arr):
    _dict = {}
    for key in arr:
        if key not in _dict:
            _dict[key] = 1
        else:
            _dict[key] += 1
    _max_key = 0
    _max_cnt = 0
    for key, value in _dict.items():
        if (value > _max_cnt) or (value == _max_cnt and key < _max_key):
            _max_key = key
            _max_cnt = value
    return _max_key
```

The old code works with `arr = [1,1,2,2,3]`.  However it fails with `arr = [2,2,1,1,3]`.  That is because `2` shows up before `1` while their counts tie.  Having only `value > _max_cnt` as the update condition was insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Using Counter from *collections* is ideal for this. Counter has a *most_common* function that returns a list of tuples ordered in terms of occurrences so we can utilise that as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4]

def migratoryBirds(arr):
    c = Counter(arr)
    m = c.most_common()[0][1]
    return min(k for k, v in c.items() if v == m)

print(migratoryBirds(arr))
```

**Output:**

```
3
```

**Note:**

The "max" value is calculated outside of the generator for efficiency

Answer (score 0):

I found what the question is.  It specifically states that in case of two birds having an equal count, you must return the one with the smallest id.  There is no guarantee that you are iterating through the id's in increasing id order.

```
if _dict[key] > _max_cnt or (_dict[key] == _max_cnt and key < _max_key):
```

You could also improve your code using:

```
for key, value in _dict.items():
```

rather than fetching `_dict[key]` twice.